# Classify the singularity of a simple pole

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

**Definitions of a pole :**

1. The isolated singularity $z_0$ is a pole, of order $k$ $\iff$ $a_{−k}≠0$ and $a_n=0$ for all $n<−k$.
2. $f(z)$ has a pole at $z_0$ if $z_0$ is an isolated singularity and $\lim_{z\to z_0}|f(z)|=\infty$

Is anyone could explain to me in details why both definition are equivalent?

Comment: Some missing context needs to be supplied in order to prove these definitions are equivalent.  Notice that the second definition is pretty well self-contained, needing only the notion of "isolated singularity" for its application to a function.  The first definition appears to reference a Laurent expansion, as otherwise the appearances of $a_n$ are unexplained in connection with the function $f(z)$ in the second definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simplifies the notation to translation the entire plane so that $z_0$ is at $0$.  You have forgotten to mention a *very important* property of $f$ that I am not going to provide for you.

Your description in 1 is too abbreviated.  The singularity of the [something goes here] function, $f$, at $0$ is a pole of order $k$ if and only if the Laurent expansion of $f$ centered at $0$ has nonzero $-k^\text{th}$ coefficient and zero $n\text{th}$ coefficients for $n<-k$.  This means the Laurent expansion of $z^k f(k)$ is a power series with nonzero constant term.  This is enough to show that $0$ is isolated from the other poles of $f$ and that the limit of interest is of $a_{-k} \, z^{-k} \rightarrow \infty$ (but you need to say a bit more than I have).

To go the other way, realize that the given limit implies $1/|f| = \left| \frac{1}{f} \right| \rightarrow 0$.  Because $f$ is [something] and we have our other hypothesis, we can write $1/f$ as a power series with leading coefficent zero.  Equivalently, $1/f(z) = z^k \hat{f}(z)$ for some positive integer $k$ and some $\hat{f}$ having nonzero constant coefficient.  Then by division, you get the statement you wrote as 1.